Removing the lines on the right and left of the razor blade shape in CSS
image
I made a razor shape for my website, but there are two thin lines on the right and left. This problem is found as follows. If you play with the responsive section distances and width in the review mode.


var girisButonlar = document.querySelectorAll(".giris_buton");
var kayitButonlar = document.querySelectorAll(".kayit_buton");
var gformlar = document.querySelectorAll(".giris_form");
var kayitFormlar = document.querySelectorAll(".kayit_form");

girisButonlar.forEach(function(girisButon, index) {
  girisButon.addEventListener("click", function() {
    gformlar[index].style.display = "flex";
    kayitFormlar[index].style.display = "none";
  });
});

kayitButonlar.forEach(function(kayitButon, index) {
  kayitButon.addEventListener("click", function() {
    kayitFormlar[index].style.display = "flex";
    gformlar[index].style.display = "none";
  });
});
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@400..700&family=Lato&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #18181B;
}

.footer-left {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #7843E6;
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.footer-left::after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  border-left: 7vw solid #7843E6;
  border-bottom: 100vh solid #18181B;
  z-index: -1;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.footer-left p {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: "Dancing Script", cursive;
  margin: 10px 15px;
}

.footer-left img {
  align-self: center;
  width: 20vw;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.footer-left .right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.footer-left .right h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 4vw;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  line-height: 95%;
}

.footer-left .right h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1vw;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  line-height: 95%;
}

.footer-right {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: center;
  width: 35%;
  background: #18181B;
}

.footer-right label {
  color: white;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-right .buttons {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 20px;
}

.footer-right .buttons button {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  color: #7843E6;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.footer-right form {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-right input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #7843E6;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.footer-right input::placeholder {
  color: white;
}

.footer-right form button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  color: #7843E6;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (width < 1450px) {
  .footer-left img {
    align-self: center;
    width: 20vw;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  .footer-left .right h1 {
    font-size: 4vw;
  }
  .footer-left .right h2 {
    font-size: 1.3vw;
    margin: 2px;
  }
  .footer-right form {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (width < 1090px) {
  .container {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .footer-left {
    display: none;
  }
  .footer-right {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .mobile .box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    width: 90%;
    background: #7843E6;
    border-radius: 15px;
  }
  .mobile .box h1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    text-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  .mobile .box img {
    width: 200px;
  }
  .mobile .buttons {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  .mobile .buttons button {
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
    color: #7843E6;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0px 3px;
  }
  .mobile label {
    color: white;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.3rem;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .mobile form {
    display: flex;
    width: 70%;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.3rem;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .mobile input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #7843E6;
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }
  .mobile input::placeholder {
    color: white;
  }
  .mobile form button {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
    color: #7843E6;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
}
<div class="container">
  <!-- DESKTOP -->
  <div class="footer-left">
    <div class="items">
      <p>Kayıp eşya</p>
      <img src="src/pixelcut-export.png">

      <div class="right">
        <h1>EŞYANI MI <br> KAYBETTİN?</h1>
        <h2>Kayıp eşya web sitesiyle eşyana hızlıca ulaşabilirsin</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-right">
    <label>Hemen Başlamaya <br> Ne Dersin?</label>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="giris_buton">Giriş</button>
      <button class="kayit_buton">Kayıt</button>
    </div>
    <form action="control.php" method="post" class="giris_form">
      <input type="text" name="kadi" placeholder="Kullanıcı Adınız...">
      <input type="password" name="sifre" placeholder="Şifreniz...">
      <button>Gönder</button>
    </form>
    <form action="kayit.php" method="post" class="kayit_form" style="display: none;">
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="TC'niz...">
      <input type="text" name="ad" placeholder="İsminiz...">
      <input type="password" name="kadi" placeholder="Kullanıcı Adınız...">
      <input type="password" name="sifre" placeholder="Şifreniz...">
      <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Şifreniz Tekrar...">
      <button>Gönder</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- DESKTOP END -->
  <!-- MOBİLE -->
  <div class="mobile">
    <div class="box">
      <h1>Eşyanı Mı Kaybettin?</h1>
      <img src="src/pixelcut-export.png">
    </div>
    <label>Hemen Başlamaya <br> Ne Dersin?</label>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="giris_buton">Giriş</button>
      <button class="kayit_buton">Kayıt</button>
    </div>
    <form action="control.php" method="post" class="giris_form">
      <input type="text" name="kadi" placeholder="Kullanıcı Adınız...">
      <input type="password" name="sifre" placeholder="Şifreniz...">
      <button>Gönder</button>
    </form>
    <form action="kayit.php" method="post" class="kayit_form" style="display: none;">
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="TC'niz...">
      <input type="text" name="ad" placeholder="İsminiz...">
      <input type="password" name="kadi" placeholder="Kullanıcı Adınız...">
      <input type="password" name="sifre" placeholder="Şifreniz...">
      <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Şifreniz Tekrar...">
      <button>Gönder</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>



How can I remove these lines?

can you share the source code of the page in some live js complier or embed html/js/css on stackoverflow...?

here: https://github.com/S0LEUS/kayipesya

are you trying to acheive something like this? https://codepen.io/elfadili-ae/pen/yLWezaQ

@abdessamad-el yes, but the problem in my code is also valid in yours. If you go into review mode and increase the width and height in the responsive section, you will see that I have a problem.

Please put just enough code into the question so we can see the problem for ourselves. Please don't expect us to go to an external site - the site may disappear (or be corrected), rendering your question useless for future readers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

@wasit-shafi I just edited my post, you can run it on stackoverflow. If this is not what you mean, can you please explain?

I have used all the you have provided, i don't see that outlines as you are embedding the code here you need some url for image for that i have just replaced the image src attribute
UPDATE added some changes



@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@400..700&family=Lato&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #18181B;
}

.footer-left {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #7843E6;
    z-index: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.footer-left::after {
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width:7vw;
    height: 100vh;
    height: 100%; 
    right: -1px;
    background: linear-gradient(
        to top left,
        #18181b 50%,
        #7843e6 50%,
        #7843e6 100%
        );
    /* NOTE: THOSE LINES ARE THE BACKGROUND, STRANGE!! IT MAY BE RELATED TO HOW BROWSER HANDLE VERY LESS ZOOM EG: 20% OR IT SEEMS SOMETHING RELATED TO SPACE ON DEVICE WHEN ITS LESS THAT 1PX */
    /* background-color: red */
    /* border-left: 7vw solid #7843E6; */
    /* border-bottom: 100vh solid #18181B; */
    z-index: -1;
}   

.items{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.footer-left  p{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: "Dancing Script", cursive;
    margin: 10px 15px;
}

.footer-left img{
    align-self: center;
    width: 20vw;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-top: 70px;
    
}

.footer-left .right{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.footer-left .right h1{
    color: white;
    font-size: 4vw;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    line-height: 95%;
}

.footer-left .right h2{
    color: white;
    font-size: 1vw;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    line-height: 95%;
}

.footer-right{
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: center;
    width: 35%;
    background: #18181B;
}

.footer-right label{
    color: white;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer-right .buttons{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 20px;
}

.footer-right .buttons button{
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
    color: #7843E6;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.footer-right form{
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer-right input{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #7843E6;
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.footer-right input::placeholder{
    color: white;
}

.footer-right form button{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
    color: #7843E6;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.mobile{
    display: none;
}



@media screen and (width < 1450px) {

    .footer-left img{
        align-self: center;
        width: 20vw;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .footer-left .right h1{
        font-size: 4vw;
    }

    .footer-left .right h2{
        font-size: 1.3vw;
        margin: 2px;
    }

    
    .footer-right form{
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }
    
    
}

@media screen and (width < 1090px) {

    .container{
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .footer-left {
        display: none;
    }

    .footer-right {
        display: none;
    }

    .mobile{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .mobile .box{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 10px 0px;
        width: 90%;
        background: #7843E6;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }

    .mobile .box h1{
        color: white;
        font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        padding: 10px 0px;
        text-wrap: nowrap;
    }

    .mobile .box img{
        width: 200px;
    }

    .mobile .buttons{
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        margin: 20px;
    }
    
    .mobile .buttons button{
        width: auto;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: none;
        border: 0;
        color: #7843E6;
        font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
        border-radius: 15px;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        margin: 0px 3px;
    }

    .mobile label{
        color: white;
        font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
        font-size: 2.3rem;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .mobile form{
        display: flex;
        width: 70%;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        color: white;
        font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
        font-size: 2.3rem;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .mobile input{
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        color: white;
        background-color: #7843E6;
        outline: none;
        border: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px 0px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        font-size: 1.3rem;
    }
    
    .mobile input::placeholder{
        color: white;
    }
    
    .mobile form button{
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: none;
        border: 0;
        color: #7843E6;
        font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
        border-radius: 15px;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Kayıp Eşya | Ana Sayfa</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="anasayfa2.css?v=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <!-- DESKTOP -->
        <div class="footer-left">
            <div class="items">
                <p>Kayıp eşya</p>
                <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dtlx6i2m7/image/upload/v1716056237/k0fegrbzcjcuvbotxkt9.png">

                <div class="right">
                    <h1>EŞYANI MI <br> KAYBETTİN?</h1>
                    <h2>Kayıp eşya web sitesiyle eşyana hızlıca ulaşabilirsin</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-right">
            <label>Hemen Başlamaya <br> Ne Dersin?</label>

            <div class="buttons">
                <button class="giris_buton">Giriş</button>
                <button class="kayit_buton">Kayıt</button>
            </div>

            <form action="control.php" method="post" class="giris_form">
                <input type="text" name="kadi" placeholder="Kullanıcı Adınız...">
                <input type="password" name="sifre" placeholder="Şifreniz...">
                <button>Gönder</button>
            </form>

            <form action="kayit.php" method="post" class="kayit_form" style="display: none;">
                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="TC'niz...">
                <input type="text" name="ad" placeholder="İsminiz...">
                <input type="password" name="kadi" placeholder="Kullanıcı Adınız...">
                <input type="password" name="sifre" placeholder="Şifreniz...">
                <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Şifreniz Tekrar...">
                <button>Gönder</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- DESKTOP END -->

        <!-- MOBİLE -->
        <div class="mobile">
            <div class="box">
                <h1>Eşyanı Mı Kaybettin?</h1>
                <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dtlx6i2m7/image/upload/v1716056237/k0fegrbzcjcuvbotxkt9.png">
            </div>

            <label>Hemen Başlamaya <br> Ne Dersin?</label>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button class="giris_buton">Giriş</button>
                <button class="kayit_buton">Kayıt</button>
            </div>

            <form action="control.php" method="post" class="giris_form">
                <input type="text" name="kadi" placeholder="Kullanıcı Adınız...">
                <input type="password" name="sifre" placeholder="Şifreniz...">
                <button>Gönder</button>
            </form>

            <form action="kayit.php" method="post" class="kayit_form" style="display: none;">
                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="TC'niz...">
                <input type="text" name="ad" placeholder="İsminiz...">
                <input type="password" name="kadi" placeholder="Kullanıcı Adınız...">
                <input type="password" name="sifre" placeholder="Şifreniz...">
                <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Şifreniz Tekrar...">
                <button>Gönder</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script>
        var girisButonlar = document.querySelectorAll(".giris_buton");
        var kayitButonlar = document.querySelectorAll(".kayit_buton");
        var gformlar = document.querySelectorAll(".giris_form");
        var kayitFormlar = document.querySelectorAll(".kayit_form");

        girisButonlar.forEach(function (girisButon, index) {
            girisButon.addEventListener("click", function () {
                gformlar[index].style.display = "flex";
                kayitFormlar[index].style.display = "none";
            });
        });

        kayitButonlar.forEach(function (kayitButon, index) {
            kayitButon.addEventListener("click", function () {
                kayitFormlar[index].style.display = "flex";
                gformlar[index].style.display = "none";
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>




Thanks for your work Shafi but the problem is not solved I checked the code on the device and saw that the problem persists. To see the problem I'm talking about, you need to go into inspect mode, open the toggle device toolbar, and play with the height and width to see.

@Soleus yes now i was also getting that lines, few things i have noticed those lines only are visible when the zoom in dev tools is less eg: 20% & upon resizing either left line is visible or only right or both or both are not visble!! it seems something related to web browser, as of now i have add right= -1px as a fallback + replaced the border with a gradient which seems more stable to me, also one simple approach will be if you can simply get the svg asset for that. Just FYI: approx 2-3 years ago i also faced a similar issue in my previous company, i am currently not able to find that issue

Hello again Shafi, I got your code and I saw that the lines disappear on more devices but if you increase the width and height I can see the lines but the lines are thinner than before, thanks for your work have a good day. Edit: i change the right:-1px; with left: 1vw; in code. I changed it to and saw that the problem was solved.
